# Template specialization within template specialized class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

The following compiles in Visual Studio 2015

```
template <int> struct Test;

template <> struct Test<0> {
    template <int> static void foo();
    template <> static void foo<0>() {}
    template <> static void foo<1>() {}
};
```

But GCC 5.2 complains error: template-id 'foo<0>' in declaration of primary template
  template <> static void foo<0>() {}

How to fix the code so that it compiles in both compilers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<int> struct Test;

template<> struct Test<0> {
    template<int> static void foo();

};

template<> void Test<0>::foo<0>() {}
template<> void Test<0>::foo<1>() {}
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

This should work in g++ and MSVC alike:

```
template <int>
struct Test;

template <>
struct Test<0>
{
  template <int>
  static void foo();
};
template <>
void Test<0>::foo<1>()
{
}

int main()
{
  Test<0>::foo<1>();
}
```